# How do i check, if two Circles are intersecting in Processing?

Tags: java, processing

So I'm currently learning Java, and i struggle a lot to get my Code working.
I made a "Fun" Code in which some circles are popping up and it calculates how many of them are on the Upper Side of the Screen. (I know, some silly code.)
I'm coding it in the "Processing" Environment, Language is Java.

Here's my main File:

```
Circle[] circles = new Circle[50];

int index = 0;
boolean finished = false;

void setup() {
  size(900, 900);
  background(0);

  for(int i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
    circles[i] = new Circle();
  }

  if(finished = true) {
  }
}

void draw() {
  if(index < circles.length) {
    circles[index].show(circles);
    index++;
  } else {
    finished = true;
  }
}

void count(Circle[] arr) {
  int n = 0;
  for(Circle c : arr) {
    if(c.getY() > height / 2) {
      n++;
    }
  }
  println(n);
}
```

And here's the "Problem" Circle class:

```
class Circle {
  private int x, y;
  private float r = random(10, 25);

  Circle() {
    this.x = Math.round(random(0 + r, width - r));
    this.y = Math.round(random(0 + r, height - r));
  }

  public int getX() {
    return this.x;
  }

  public int getY() {
    return this.y;
  }

  public void show(Circle[] arr) {
    if(isColliding(arr)) {
      this.x = Math.round(random(0 + r, width - r));
      this.y = Math.round(random(0 + r, height - r));
    } else {
      ellipse(this.x, this.y, r * 2, r * 2);
      stroke(255);
      fill(255);
    }
  }

  public boolean isColliding(Circle[] arr) {
    boolean result = false;
    if(arr == null) {
      result = false;
    } else {
      for(Circle c : arr) {
      float d = dist(c.getX(), c.getY(), this.x, this.y);
        if(d < r * 2) {
          result = true;
          println("Collision at: " + c.getX() + " " + c.getY());
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

As you can see, i already have a isColliding Method, and the Outputs in the Console seem to be right, however it won't work in the show() Method, the Circles won't stop intersecting each other.

So how can i make it work, that the Position is re-calculated when it is colliding?

Comment: Your code has some uninitialized variables like width and heigh and methods like random that are missing from your example.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. Maybe i should add that it's in Java. The random Method is already implemented and variables like height and width are in the Processing Environment implemented as i put a size in the box. For a better saying, the code works just fine, but the isColliding Method,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your collision method works? Unless I'm missing something, it should ALWAYS return true as you're passing in an array that includes itself.

That aside, I'd start looking at how your show() logic is laid out. You are checking for overlap, and then assigning a new random position if it finds any. This new position could very likely be on a circle that has already been drawn and in a good position.

Put your re-positioning in a loop so that it checks to make sure that it didn't just place itself onto an existing circle.

```
public void show(Circle[] arr) 
{
    /* 
      You could potentially get into a situation where you will NEVER find an empty spot. 
      Add an escape method for the loop.
    */
    int failLimit = 500;
    while(failLimit-- > 0 && isColliding(arr))
    {
        this.x = Math.round(random(0 + r, width - r));
        this.y = Math.round(random(0 + r, height - r));
    }
    ellipse(this.x, this.y, r * 2, r * 2);
    stroke(255);
    fill(255);
}
```

You could simplify this and make it a bit more efficient by spawning in circles one at a time, checking to make sure their positions are good then.

Comment: Well, that's actually it. I didn't think of the fact the the Array already includes the new Circle, which would explain why it doesn't draw show anything if i used a while Loop. Thank's a lot! I'm going to put an extra ArrayList<Circle> in my Code and add every Circle after the show() Method.!!